# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine

Tags: qt, yocto, qtwebengine

I have compiled a framebuffer (without x11 and wayland) image for wandboard-quad with Yocto Jethro.  I have used the Freescale Community BSP Jethro branch.The image contains most of the Qt 5.5 components and Qt Web Engine.

The qmake version is 5.5.1 from meta-toolchain-qt5 and Qt Creator is 5.5 as well.

I created the quick nano browser example to test the functionalities.  But, Qt Creator gives me this `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine` when I cross compile to wandboard.  Desktop compile is fine though.

Anyone knows what is wrong?

**Edit**: I have follow how to set up Qt Creator in this [Set Up Instruction](http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=HIO_Wiki:Set_Up_Qt_Creator_for_Yocto_Device)

**Edit**: First of all, Qt WebEngine has 2 versions: the open-source and the licensed one.  Based on what ICS people said, there is barely any differences between the 2 versions.

Qt Webengine is not available in the SDK `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bb`.  Therefore, it does not contain the all the Qt Web Engine Components.

To add Qt WebEngine to the SDK, I have modified the `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bb` by adding `qtwebengine-dev` and `qtwebengine-mkspecs`

**Question:** qmake does not recognize Qt Webengine module even all the necessary files are present in the sysroot.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding (sorry no reference to hand),  but cross compiling `webengine` is only supported on the paid for enterprise edition of Qt.

Comment: [http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qtwebengine/2014-October/000106.html](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qtwebengine/2014-October/000106.html) The people at the qtcompany replied that only the Enterprise version has the fully supported SDK and Platform.

Comment: Supported in the sense of "we'll look into your issues". It doesn't mean that there's anything missing from the open source version that prevents cross-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's documented anywhere, but Qt WebEngine is only available on desktop platforms.  You might try using the lightweight [WebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html) control instead.

Comment: [http://www.qt.io/qt5-5](http://www.qt.io/qt5-5) At the Part of "Browser Engine" example, it said "QtWebEngine running on Freescale i.MX6, which is exactly the Arm Processor I am using.  So it should work but I need to know which to modify

Answer (score 0):

No Wayland or Server, you can compile with support EGLFS. In its add image recipe:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "wayland x11"
DISTRO_FEATURES + = "opengl"

PACKAGECONFIG_GL_pn-qtbase = "gles2 linuxfb"
PACKAGECONFIG [gles2] = "-opengl s2 -eglfs,, virtual / virtual / egl libgles2"
```

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to QtWebEngine.  Instead, it is for qtbase.

Comment: This is necessary for qtbase own resources to EGLFS, QtWebEngine alone does nothing in EGLFS and qtbase is inheritance for other Qt modules.

Comment: Still, I have all those in my `local.conf` except linuxfb and still missing the Qt WebEngine module.

Comment: I built some images with Yocto supporting QtWebEngine and even modified flags for Chromium and **QtWebEngine** recipe did not change anything for X11, Wayland, LinuxFrameBuffer, EGLFS, OpenGL2 and others.

Only in local.conf and **qtbase_%. bbappend**.