# Yocto SDK, QtWebEngine: Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine

Tags: qt5, yocto, qtwebengine

I'm doing my first steps with Qt and QtWebEngine on an embedded board (i.MX6), using Yocto. Using provided example recipes, like the *quicknanobrowser*, works nicely on the target. So I can't confirm [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426818/5226287) which claims that WebEngine is not available on embedded platforms.

Now I want to write my own QML application and deploy it on the board. With the recipe `meta-toolchain-qt5` I created an SDK and installed it. In QtCreator I set all paths to the SDK installation and tried to build it, but got this error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine
11:13:13: The process "/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake" exited with code 3.
```

It turned out that WebEngine was not included in the SDK. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36324486/5226287), I fixed that by putting the following to my own `packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bbappend` file:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
    qtwebengine \
    qtwebengine-qmlplugins \
    qtquickcontrols-qmlplugins \
    qtwebengine-examples \
"
```

Then reinstalled the SDK. Now it seems that all WebEngine files are available in the SDK installation (the `zsh` glob pattern below matches all directories in any subdirectory of `/opt/poky/1.8/`, which contain "webengine", case-insensitively):

```
% ls -1 -d (#i)/opt/poky/1.8/**/*webengine*(/)
/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWebEngine/
/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWebEngine/5.4.3/QtWebEngine/
/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWebEngineWidgets/
/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWebEngineWidgets/5.4.3/QtWebEngineWidgets/
/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/qml/QtWebEngine/
/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qt5/examples/webengine/
/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qt5/examples/webenginewidgets/
/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/share/qt5/translations/qtwebengine_locales/
```

Still, I get the same *Unknown module* error. This is independent of QtCreator, and can also be shown by directly calling qmake:

```
% source /opt/poky/1.8/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
% /opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake /home/me/test/test.pro -r -spec linux-oe-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine
```

The project itself should be fine, because it compiles and runs without problems on the Desktop installation.

Any ideas? Are there maybe still some files missing in the SDK? Where does qmake search for the modules? How can I tell qmake where to find the WebEngine installation?

Answer (score 0):

In `/opt/poky/1.8/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`

add `sh /opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/environment-setup.d/qt5.sh`

This will set up the Qt5 environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, this file is already sourced inside `/opt/poky/1.8/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`. So adding it or even sourcing it manually doesn't help.

Comment: try to follow this wiki to set up Qt creator http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=HIO_Wiki:Set_Up_Qt_Creator_for_Yocto_Device